# Clickable image on email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, href

I want to be able to display images that the user can click on an e-mail through vba, so far I have a picture and text but I dont know how to make it so that the person who receives the email can click on the image so that it will send them to a webpage.

```
   Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    'OutApp.Session.logon
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next

    Fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Logo.jpg"

    Dim cid As String
                    With OutMail

                    .to = companymail
                    .Subject = "Email Title"

                    .Body = strBody
                    .HTMLBody = "<html><p>First Text</p>" & _
                     "<img src=""cid:Logo.jpg""height=80 width=400>" & "<html><p>Second Text </p>"
                     .Attachments.Add Fname, 1, 0
                    .Attachments.Add fileaddress
                    .Display
                    End With

    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End If
```

Comment: Add an href tag. [Read this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp)

Comment: Your second open-HTML tag `<html>` is wrong. You only need one, at the top level of the document, and it should contain a single `<body>` tag that contains all the `<p>`s, `img`s, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the `<img>` tag with `<a>` tag:

```
<a href="URL/target.html">
<img src="src=""cid:Logo.jpg"" height=80 width=400 alt="an image" title="The title of this image" style="border-style:none"/>
</a>
```

Also, remember that you need to set up a well formed HTML markup for the HTMLBody property. That means you can't specify anything after closing `<html>` tag. You must keep the structure.